# Laravel Queues vs Kafka/RabbitMQ

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue

At our company we currently sending around 1.5 to 2 million text messages per month using various services like Ring Ring, Nexmo, Twilio, ... This is currently done by some old cronjob script we wrote 10 years ago. We are finally about to rewrite the complete structure and start using queues instead. We are trying to decide whether to use the build-in Laravel Queues (Redis) or a full-blown messaging queue like Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ. We currently tend to just use Laravel Queues as we already have experience with these for sending some emails and webhooks (not at a 2-3 million per month scale). Things like Laravel Horizon and the easy configurability of the queues is also an advantage.

Does anyone have experience with running 2-3 million jobs a month using Laravel Queues? I don't think this will be an issue performance wise. I am currently not seeing and reason to use Kafka/RabbitMQ over the built-in Laravel Queues tbf. Am I missing something or are there any potential problems we can run into when using Laravel Queues? Any concerns or general advise, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like your approach, did you get a way around this? Is Laravel Horizon handling the large scale request load?

Comment: @moseskamau We are still implementing so not operational yet. However, I don't see an issue why it could handle this load tbf.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Noted. Laravel is designed to handle high loads, so the queues should work fine.

Comment: Here is someone who runs Laravel Horizon at large scale (~25M jobs a month) and it just works fine. So yes, if the server can handle the load it is fine. You can adjust the workers for your own needs and spawn as many as you want. As a tip: Use different queues for different usages and don't spawn all jobs into `default`. And we use for each queue an own worker (or more workers), so that full queues does not affect nearly empty queues. Also: Workers with no load need not much resources and can be run without load without any problems. And use tags for jobs, so you can find them after queuing.

Comment: @Jordi I have done similar type of work in one product where we are sending push notification to all our registered users at a single time from admin panel. Around per day we are sending approx 30000-40000 notifications to all over registered user at a time with message all brodcast. We have used queue job default and found server cpu reach 80% after some time. So we have separted that bulk notification sending in redis based queue and normal with default database base inside Laravel. Now from Redis there is no affect on High CPU and execution is also 70% fast compare with default.